# solc-v0.6.0: TypeError: Operator - not compatible with types tuple() and int_const 1

Tags: solc

I am having this error on solc version `0.6.0`.

Basically I am returning length of the list and subtract 1 from it, where that value will be assigned to an `uint` variable.

In general this command used to return the length of the list after the push:

`uint length = list.push(Struct({val: value}))`

---

```
TypeError: Operator - not compatible with types tuple() and int_const 1
uint32 value = uint32(list.push(Interval({endpoint: startTime})) - 1);
```

I was not getting this error or `solc-v0.5.*`. 
I feel like tuples does not return their length any more.

**[Q]** How could I fix this error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, `list.push` will not return the length of it anymore.

From https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.0/060-breaking-changes.html#how-to-update-your-code:

> Change `uint length = array.push(value)` to `array.push(value);`. The new length can be accessed via array.length.

So, now you must do it "manually":

```
pragma solidity 0.6.0;

contract Test {
    struct Interval {
        uint endpoint;
    }

    Interval[] public list;

    function addItemAndGetLengthMinusOne() public returns(uint) {
        list.push(Interval({endpoint: now}));
        uint value = list.length - 1;

        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah this is pretty inefficient and will consume additional gas to access list again, I am not sure why they updated like this. So does `list.push()` return the latest pushed tuple?

Comment: I agree. Now, `list.push` will return the tuple _itself_, as far as I can gather.

Comment: Like only `list` itself?

Comment: Not `list` itself, because that would be the array. I'm not sure at this point, but I think what you get is the encoded tuple. For instance, you cannot do `value = list.push(Interval({endpoint: now})).length;` That won't work.

Comment: So I can do as follows: `Interval ret = list.push(Interval({endpoint: now}));` and than `ret.now` will return the last push items `now` variable

Comment: You can't. When you try to do that, the compiler complains `list.push` is not returning anything at all, actually. Not even bytes. If you use something like `bytes memory value = list.push(Interval({endpoint: now}))` it won't work either.
* So, I was wrong about list.push returning something. Apparently it doesn't.

Comment: It is interesting :/